# How to store arraylist items in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

Just a very small question.

I have a array list named `li`, where after my conditions I have the contents as:

```
li[0]="s";
li[1]="a";
li[2]="h";
li[3]="i";
li[4]="4";
```

Now I wrote the code as:

```
foreach (string value in li)
{
    tb_output.Text = li.ToString();
}
```

Here, I want that for each list item, the elements should be stored in a string, which I want to display it in a textbox. But i am unable to get "sahil" in tb_output.

Can you tell me where I am wrong. I am unable to take it. I am a beginner, so it is a kind of trouble to me.

Comment: you could try some of the answers bellow or use StringBuffer: var buff = new StringBuffer(); foreach (...) { buff.Append(value); } tb_output.Text = buff.ToString(); StringBuffer should be faster than concatenation with +.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers should work for your particular question, however, if you want to write to that textbox the contents of **li**, you should instead do it in this manner.

```
string word = "";
foreach(string s in li)
{
    word += s;
}
tb_output.Text = s;
```

That way, you clear out the textbox each time you write the array to it.

Better yet, especially if are dealing with a large array, improve performance by using StringBuilder (which you can get by adding "using System.Text;" to the top of your file.

```
StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(string s in li)
{
    stb.Append(s);
}
tb_output.Text = stb.ToString();
```

Comment: Getting exception,,
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Char' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: @user2387900 Your code in the description is assigning to indexes on the array like this: li[0]="s"; That seems to indicate to me that you are using a string array.  Are you instead using a char array with code like: li[0]='s'; ?

Answer (score 8):

If `li` is a `char[]`, use `tb_output.Text = new String(li)`

If `li` is a `List<char>`, use `tb_output.Text = new String(li.ToArray())`

If `li` is a `string[]` or `List<string>`, use `tb_output.Text = String.Concat(li)`

Otherwise, if `li` contains `char`s, use `tb_output.Text = new String(li.Cast<char>().ToArray())`

Otherwise, if `li` contains `string`, use `tb_output.Text = String.Concat(li.Cast<string>())`

Comment: For" tb_output.Text = String.Join("", li)", getting-- System.Collections.ArrayList
For "tb_output.Text = String.Join("", li.Cast<string>())"--getting--
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Char' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: There's no point in using `Join` with no separator.  Just use `Concat`.  That's literally why `Concat` exists.

Comment: @MichaelGunter Unfortunately, I didnt got the answer by any of this comments..but thanks alot for ur help.
I got the answer by the line "tb_output.Text = new string((char[])myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(char)));"...but I am still figuring out what does it state..can u help me..
and my li was a arraylist..

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid using ArrayLists whenever possible. Either use `List<char>` or `char[]` array. I've used `char` because you're only holding `chars` but you can change this to `string` if you're going to use more than one character.

With a char array, you can simply do this

```
string myString  = new string(li);
```

Alternatively, you can simply use the [String.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx) method and pass in the List or Array.

```
tb_output.Text = String.Concat(myArrayOrList);
```

**Update for clarification of comment**

If you want to use a `List<T>`, you can do this.

```
List<char> li = new List<char>() { 's', 'a', 'h', 'i', 'l' };
tb_output.Text = String.Concat(li);
```

If you really must use an `ArrayList` here then you can simply convert that ArrayList to an array of chars and use the first method described above (`new string(myCharArray)`)

```
try
{
    tb_output.Text = new string((char[])myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(char)));
}
catch(InvalidCastException ex)
{ 
    //handle any problems with the casting
}
```

I've added a `try..catch` block for the ArrayList because if there's an element in the array list that can't be cast to a `char` then an `InvalidCastException` is thrown. This isn't generally needed with a `List<char>` because you know that the list can only have `chars` in them whereas an ArrayList can have any object type.

**Update 2 based on comments**

The line `new string((char[])myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(char))` can be broken down.

First we are converting the `ArrayList` to an `Array` using the the method [ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.toarray.aspx)

```
myArrayList.ToArray();
```

However, we want to tell the `ToArray` method to convert every object inside to the ArrayList to a `char` because, at the moment, the ArrayList is holding `object` types and not `char` types. So we pass that information into the method.

```
myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(char));
```

We can create a new string from an array of chars by doing

```
string newString = new string(arrayOfChars);
```

At the moment we have an `Array` from the `ToArray` method but the `string` constructor here needs an array of chars (`char[]`) so we cast the `Array` that we have to a `char[]` which is why we have

```
(char[])myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(char));
```

So we now have a `char[]` from the original ArrayList and can pass that into the `string` constructor.

```
new string((char[])myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(char)));
```

You still haven't given a reason for why you're using an `ArrayList` but you'll have to deal with potential performance issues and casting exceptions as you may accidentally put an object into the ArrayList that can't be converted into a `char` (which is why we have the `Try..Catch` block).

Comment: System.Collections.ArrayList is returned in the textbox. Not getting

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `ArrayLists`? They are outdated and, in most situations, should only be used if you're targeting below .Net 2.0 or working with legacy code. You should use `List<T>` or a normal array instead. List<T> is more like an ArrayList as you don't need to know the size beforehand and you can keep adding more elements.

Comment: tb_output.Text = new string((char[])myArrayList.ToArray(typeof(char)));
...I got the answer by this line..but i didnt understood the line at al..Can you please explain me..

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation. There is no reason why I used Array List. May be because I was starting with data structure and learned arraylist is dynamic. So tried with it.
So, when should I be using arraylist ??? Here, If I try with hash table, would it be fine ??

Comment: @user2387900 - I see. If you know how many characters you want store, then you can just use `char[] charArray = new char[5];`. If you want it more like an ArrayList (where you can add and remove characters because you don't know how many there will be), you can use `List<char>`. ArrayLists should generally only be used if you're targeting the .NET 1.0 framework (which is unlikely if you're not working with old, existing code or on a specialised project). Most of the times you can use `List<T>` instead. The `T` means it's generic so it could be `List<char>`, `List<int>`, `List<MyOwnClass>` etc

Answer (score 2):

How about trying

```
foreach (string value in li)
{
    tb_output.Text += value;
}
```

Comment: getting--- System.Collections.ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You need to append with **+=**

```
foreach (string value in li)
{
   tb_output.Text += li.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Getting----Unable to cast object of type 'System.Char' to type 'System.String'....in foreach (string value in li) line... I dont know where to proceed

Answer (score 0):

You can join all elements from an array using [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) method.

It takes two parameters, the first is: "join with what?", you can join the elements and separate them with a comma for example. The second parameter is your `IEnumerable<T>`, you can join elements of a `List<T>` and anything that comes from `IEnumerable<T>`.

So you could do

```
tb_output.Text = String.Join("", li);
```

This will return the string `sahi4` as we are joining the array with an empty string.

Or you can use [`String.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991828.aspx) already mentioned by `keyboardP`.

```
tb_output.Text = String.Concat(li);
```

Which will concatenate all values.

---

Alternatively you could build the string using a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string value in li)
{
    sb.Append(value);
}
tb_output.Text = sb.ToString(); // returns the built string
```

Foreach will return one element at time from your `li` array and put into `value` as you named it. Instead of trying to use `li.ToString()` which will convert the array to a string inside the `foreach`, you should use `value` to get the string in each position...

Also, if you are concatenating strings you should use `StringBuilder` in cases like these, but you could also use the operator `+`.

```
stringA = stringA + "B";  // or
stringA += "B";
```

Comment: There's no point in using `Join` with no separator.  Just use `Concat`.  That's literally why `Concat` exists.

Comment: Getting----Unable to cast object of type 'System.Char' to type 'System.String'....in foreach (string value in li) line...
I dont know where to proceed

Comment: @user2387900 change `string value` to `char value`